# How to identify if the DBlink created in Oracle12c is shared or not

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, dblink

I have created couple of DB links. Some are shared and some are not.

I created shared DB Link:

```
CREATE SHARED DATABASE LINK dblink_name CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password AUTHENTICATED BY schema_name IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'service_name';
```

I created Normal DBlink as:

```
create database link dblink_name connect to username identified by password using service_name;
```

Is there a way where i can identify if the dblink created is shared mode or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to check the data dictionary to determine if a link is shared or not.  Below are two workarounds, using SYS.LINK$ and DBMS_METADATA, but they each have problems.

### SYS.LINK$

The undocumented table SYS.LINK$ contains this information in a bitmap, as explained by Solomon Yakobson in [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022792):

```
select name from sys.link$ where bitand(flag,1) = 1;
```

But that table contains password hashes and is only viewable by SYS.  You could perhaps grant permission to that table, which could raise some security concerns.  Or create a view on top of it and then grant that view, although you're typically not supposed to create objects in the SYS schema.

### DBMS_METADATA

The package DBMS_METADATA recreates the link DDL and can be used to check for the "SHARED" keyword.

```
select owner, db_link
from dba_db_links
where lower(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DB_LINK', db_link, owner)) like '%create shared%';
```

This solution can be slow, especially if the system has a large number of database links.  And searching for text strings in source code may not be reliable.  According to the syntax diagrams in [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205) there are no other keywords that could come between `CREATE` and `SHARED`, but that may change or there may be undocumented features or behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon. Realy Appreciate your help. This querry helped.

Comment: @GauravMittal: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers